# How do I extract specific data from a datatable?

Tags: c#, database, datatable

I am creating a game where all my enemies are located in a database. I put the table in my datatable, but how do I access specific data in it? For example, I want to access the enemy that is an elf in the datatable. I know you can use foreach to display the entire row, but I want to only get certain values from that row to create my enemy object.

Comment: What kind of a DB are you using?

Comment: @animaonline I suppose his DB is a `System.Data.DataTable`

Comment: What exactly is your problem? It seems you're asking total basics of db querying...

Comment: @walther I think problem is in enemy elf querying. That is not same as querying orks, or friendly elfs

Comment: i am assuming your every row in datatable is an enemy and every column of the row is an attribute to enemy object. in short the datatable contains all the players ( self + all enemies) . if so , why not fetch the enemy using where clause .

Comment: @simplecoder Yes, but I only want to extract certain attributes to use as parameters in my enemy class object I will be creating

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, you always keep folks laughing around here! :D

Comment: @If so i think then you can use Linq to extract one row (enemy row) and use the columns to initialize ( enemy class)

Comment: @user2037244 please provide your table column names and code which you have problems with. Otherwise its not clear what you are asking about

Answer (score 1):

To access specific data in a `DataTable` you can do it like this:

```
dataTable.Rows[0][0]
```

or you can do it by field name:

```
dataTable.Rows[0]["field_name"]
```

and so then you can initialize your properties with statements like that.

---

If you're working with a `DataRow[]` like @lazyberezovsky is saying then it might look something like this:

```
dataRowArray[0][0]
```

or:

```
dataRowArray[0]["field_name"]
```

Comment: Not sure what he is doing, but seems something like `dataTable.Select("Race = 'Elf' AND IsEnemy = True")`

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, so you're thinking that he's working with a `DataRow[]` then?

Comment: Actually it's hard to say what he is working on, because he didn't provide neither table structure, nor code he has :) But I suppose he have problem with filtering table